# How can I put two or more faicons followed by the same name?

Tags: fonts, fontawesome

I am trying to display a Stack Overflow icon next to a Stack Exchange icon followed by my user name like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faicon{stack-overflow }\faicon{stack-exchange} \underline{}:  {cristina-hg}
\end{document}
```

However, just the last is displayed. What is wrong?

I am using the `fontawesome` package for icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can get it to work with this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
   \faStackOverflow~\faStackExchange\underline{}:  {cristina-hg}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem was the space after `stack-overflow`. In case this space was meant to be between these two items, place it between the commands:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faicon{stack-overflow} \faicon{stack-exchange} :  {cristina-hg}
\end{document}
```

[image]